# UITableViewCell doesn't change its alpha/opacity

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a regular tableview and I want its cells to begin being partially transparent (alpha = 0.85). However, when I set the alpha in the cellForRowAt function, the cells begin as being fully opaque. To specify, I want the entire cell (including its contents) to be alpha = 0.85, not just the background color.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! customTableCell
        
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section)"
        
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white        
    cell.isOpaque = false
    cell.alpha = CGFloat(0.85)
             
    return cell        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the tableView modifies/resets the cell's alpha and frame to some degree after cellForRowAt. There's another UITableViewDelegate method called tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:) which gets triggered right before the cell is shown. Accordingly, I added the following code and it worked:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {           
    cell.alpha = 0.85
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set the layer opacity:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! customTableCell
    
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section)"
    
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white        
cell.isOpaque = false
cell.layer.opacity = 0.85
         
return cell
```

}

Comment: Another way to do it:
`cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0)` 
You will need to provide the cell color in RGB value doing it this way

Comment: this works! However, this would only change the opacity fo the background and not the full cell

Comment: Correct, what else is in your cell? Text can be modified using the same method. `cell.label.textColor`

Comment: Indeed - at the moment I haven't added in all of the components yet, but I'm trying to understand if I'm doing anything wrong in the simple way. Curiously, setting the cell alpha to 0.85 as a result of scroll callbacks and behaviors *does* change the opacity, so it's specifically something about the initial load.